# when using "pyfile s:pyscript" it seems vim doesn't interpret "s:pyscript" as a variable

Tags: python, vim

A vim-script file calls a python script through:

```
let s:pyscript = resolve(expand('<sfile>:p:h:h')) . '/pyscript/deploy.py'

echom "sourcing " . s:pyscript
pyfile s:pyscript
```

the echom-command shows me the expansion points to the correct file, but the following `pyfile s:pyscript` results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] file or directory not found: '&s:pyscript'
```

Which let's me conclude, that everythin after pyfile is immediately considered "python" and vim doesn't evaluate the s:pyscript variable.

What's the way around it? Either in the python-script or the vim-"master" script is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`:execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute):

```
execute 'pyfile ' . s:pyscript
```

Comment: The second after i posted my question, i got the same idea. Just tried it and was in the process to answer myself, but you beat me to it! ;-) Thx nevertheless!

Comment: Sometimes you just don't see the forest ... - will accept your answer after the time-lapse!

Comment: Great. This info, including the process to build the path to the python script, is vital to run python scripts inside Vim, so it should be prominent in the Vim scripting docs.