# setup vim script to execute python file

Tags: python, vim, scripting

I searched SO extensively and I can't get to fix this: I'm trying to code a pathogen friendly python plugin in windows. The setup would be:

In \vimfiles\bundle\plugin I have a myscript.vim with:

```
let s:path = fnamemodify(resolve(expand('<sfile>:p')), ':h')

function! Up()
    pyfile my_script.py
endfunction

command Up :call Up()
```

then in the same directory I have my_script.py:

```
import vim
vim.current.buffer.append("here I am")
```

This setup only works when/if I load myscript.vim in Vim and run :so %. I get an error 'No such file or directory my_script.py', but from then on the  the script runs fine.

What i gather here is that the s:path line, wich sets the path for the python script call, in myscript.vim doesnt get processed when I call the function, but once the script is run I have that path available.

What I'm doing wrong, and how do I fix this? Ty all

Answer (score 2):

The answer was here, in [when using "pyfile s:pyscript" it seems vim doesn't interpret "s:pyscript" as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212385/when-using-pyfile-spyscript-it-seems-vim-doesnt-interpret-spyscript-as-a) (kudos to https://stackoverflow.com/users/200291/icktoofay) but i didnt grasp it at first glance.

The idea is to build a string with both the command pyfile and the path (including the script name), and then execute it:

So, outside the function, call:

```
let s:path = fnamemodify(resolve(expand('<sfile>:p')), ':h') . '\my_script.py
```

and then inside the function:

```
execute 'pyfile ' . s:path
```

notice there is a space after pyfile, so you're in fact 'building' the full command by a string concatenation before actually executing it.

Comment: For more information on how this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976776/how-to-get-path-to-the-current-vimscript-being-executed